# Sampling the hitting time of a Brownian motion with drift

Tags: random-variable, monte-carlo, random-generation, brownian-motion

Consider a Brownian motion with drift $\mu > 0$ and variance parameter $\sigma^2$. Then the pdf of the first hitting time to the value $a > 0$ [is](https://www.stat.uchicago.edu/%7Eyibi/teaching/stat317/2013/Lectures/Lecture25_4up.pdf)
$$
f(t) = \frac{a}{\sigma\sqrt{2\pi t^3}}\exp\bigg\{-\frac{(a-\mu t)^2}{2\sigma^2 t}\bigg\},
$$
for $t > 0$.

I have a few questions about this distribution:

1. Is this a standard distribution with a name?
2. Right now I'm sampling from this distribution using MCMC methods (the Metropolis algorithm from R's `mcmc` package). Is there hope to more efficiently sample, e.g. via inverse transform sampling, or am I stuck with MCMC?